# Kubernetes - Failed to Pull image - no such how

Tags: kubernetes, networking, docker-registry, coredns

We are taking the step to upgrade our infrastructure setup and are doing some R&D with K8s.

We believe k8s is the solution we want to implement, however I've hit a brick wall.

I'm really struggling to get k8s to pull an image from a private registry that uses a hostname that does not exist.

I have followed instructions online and have successfully added a host record to coredns - I have verified it resolves correctly using throwaway containers, yet it seems like whenever I try to pull an image, I get the same error:

```
Failed to pull image "fake.host.uk/app": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get "https://fake.host.uk/v2/": dial tcp: lookup fake.host.uk: no such host
```

Doing a `docker login fake.host.uk` works absolutely fine.
I can also see my added hosts via

`kubectl run -it --rm --restart=Never --image=infoblox/dnstools:latest dnstools`

Then running `ping fake.host.uk` brings back the correct IP.

However, trying to pull an image just doesn't work; how can I solve this problem?

Comment: From the nodes (not the containers on those nodes), does the name resolve?

Comment: Hi mate, yes, resolves fine as I added an entry directly into /etc/hosts. I've pulled the images down using docker directly, works absolutely fine!

Comment: Actually, you've just made me think - I didn't add the host record on one of the nodes!

Comment: BMitch, you're a life saver - I didn't realise all the nodes required the host, I though just the masters. Works a charm now. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you followed - https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/

Comment: @Matt, is your problem now resolved?

Comment: Hi gents, sorry for the delay - yes my problem is resolved. I had to modify my hosts file on all the nodes, not just the master like I originally thought. Not sure how I close this question as answered!

Comment: @Matt, Thanks for your response. I have posted community wiki answer to summarise the problem. You can [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). You can also write your own answer on how you solved your problem. Please do not "close" or remove your answered questions. It is not a good practise to remove the question after finding the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DNS resolution needs to be setup for each node in your cluster, preferably by updating a common DNS server, but you can also update /etc/hosts on every node in the cluster. Kubernetes and docker pull images from the node and not from within a container, so they won't see the settings applied to things like coredns (it would create a circular dependency, how do you resolve the name of the coredns image's registry).

Comment: From a 2023 perspective it currently seems to me that this is not working when the container runtime is `containerd` (as opposed to Docker).

Comment: Makes total sense once you get it served nicely. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Community wiki answer to summarise the topic:
OP has commenten, that the problem is now resolved.

> my problem is resolved. I had to modify my hosts file on all the nodes, not just the master like I originally thought.